# How can I return results for items found. but also have a list of items not found

Tags: php, html

I currently have a HTML search form which takes multiple inputs (for example: 123456, 654321, 789456). I am using PHP to search a database, to see if the numbers exist as an item number. It then returns information on those items in an echoed table.

The only issue is that if a number does not exist within the database it will return no results found, even if the other two items exist.

How can i have it so that it returns the information on the items that do exist and then lists out the items, which it was not able to find records for?

My form and table generation are below:

```
<div id="div1">
            <!-- [SEARCH FORM] -->
        <form method="post" action="nweb.php" id="testform">
        <h1>Product Information</h1>
        <!-- <input type="text" name="search" required/> -->
        <textarea name="search" cols="40" rows="5" form="testform"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
      // SEARCH FOR ITEMS
      require "2-search.php";
      
      // DISPLAY RESULTS
      if (count($results) > 0) {
        echo "number found ".count($resultsArray)."<br>";

 echo "<table>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo  "<tr>";
        echo    "<th>Item number</th>";
        echo    "<th>Stock available</th>";
        echo    "<th>Available Stock</th>";
        echo    "<th>Detailed Description</th>";
        echo    "<th>Division</th>";
        echo    "<th>Gender</th>";
        echo    "<th>Group</th>";
        echo    "<th>Subgroup</th>";
        echo  "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
      foreach ($resultsArray as $results) {
        
        foreach ($results as $r) {

            echo "<tbody>";
            echo  "<tr>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['item_number'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['stock_available'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>". $r['available_stock'] ."</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['detailed_desc'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['division'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['gender'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['group'] . "</td>";
            echo    "<td>" . $r['sub_group'] . "</td>";
            echo  "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";
   }
      }
            echo "</table>";  
      } else {
        echo "No results found";
      }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

The search code in 2-search.php is:

```
$searchFor = explode(",", trim($_POST['search']));

$resultsArray = [];

foreach ($searchFor as $searchItem){
  echo $searchItem;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT * FROM dbo.[data] WHERE [item_number] = ? ");
    $stmt->execute(["" .$searchItem . ""]);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo $searchItem;
    array_push($resultsArray, $results);
}
```

If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search terms are within your `$searchFor` array, so that's already dealt with. Now we only need to find some way to display these instead of a table. Let's modify the code that deals with the results count.

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($resultsArray as $key => $results) {
    if (count($results) > 0) {
        foreach ($results as $r) {
            echo "<tbody>";
            
            ...

            echo "</tbody>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No results found for ". $searchFor[$key];
    }
}
```

You want the count checking to be in your `foreach($resultsArray as $results)`. That way you'll check each of the `as $results` arrays. The $key contains the index for the current iteration (1st = 0, 2nd = 1, etc.,) so you can use it to access the searchedFor array, which contains your exploded search terms.

Comment: Thank you once again. The logic is now there and it works. I am very grateful for your knowledge and have learned a lot. Why would it be a case of finding another way other than a table to view the results ?

Comment: the found results would be in the same place, in my answer it's marked as three dots (...), I did that just so the unrelated code to the issue takes less space and is more readable haha. the only issue that comes to mind is that maybe the echo no results might break the table logic, so maybe put it in a <tr> or something, but that's just a matter of a minor html fix

PS going to sleep now, so if you respond, I won't see it till the next time I get on, good night